# How can i create a database using SQLite on Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I have been using SQLite-net-pcl to add a database to my application but when i try to create the database it throws this exception SQLite.SQLiteException: 'Could not open database file: mydatabase.db3 (Misuse)'.

```
public class MySQLDatabase
{
    private static SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

    public void MyDatabase()
    {
        if (db != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string databasepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "mydatbase.db3");
        db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasepath);
        db.CreateTableAsync<MyTable>();
    }

    public void InsertData(int gameid, string preorder,string rating,string standards,string overpriced,string agerating,string gameplay,string recommend,string impact)
    {
        MyTable myNewTable = new MyTable
        {
            GameId = gameid,
            PreOrder = preorder,
            Rating = rating,
            Standards = standards,
            OverPriced = overpriced,
            AgeRating = agerating,
            Gameplay = gameplay,
            Recommend = recommend,
            Impact = impact
        };
        conn.Insert(myNewTable);
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I have seen other solutions to this problem using SQLiteConnection.CreateFile() but for some reason, this method doesn't show up for me. I am using the SQLite-net-pcl 1.8.116 version.

Comment: you need to specify a path for the db file.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Comment: @Jason is there another way to create it other than the suggested way in the documentation?

Comment: What's the problem with that approach?  You can do it however you want as long as you pass the path to the `SQLiteConnection` constructor

Comment: @Jason so i can just do it like this? `conn = new SQLiteConnection("C:\Users\eliof\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2019mydatabase.db3")`

Comment: not for an iOS/Android app, because those systems have no idea what `c:\` is.  Look at the doc I linked to earlier, or read the docs on files in Xamarin Forms

Comment: @Jason i did it the way you said and it works but i can't find where the database is. I also updated the code in  question to my current code

Comment: What path did you use?  What OS are you using?  Are you using the emulator or a device?

Comment: @Jason I changed the code in the question to match my current code. Also, I am using an emulator.

Comment: again, which OS are you testing?

Comment: @Jason Sorry i didn't see that. I am using Pie9.0-API 28.

Comment: to view files on Android (emulator or device) you have to use `adb`

Comment: @Jason What is that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?adb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is method I use for create and migrate Sqlite DB in Xamarin.Forms:

```
var rootFolder = new LocalRootFolder();
var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(Path.Combine(rootFolder.Path, "my_db.sqlite"));
await connection.CreateTableAsync<My_Table>();
```